# Reopenning JQM dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi and happy new year,

There is this JQM dialog, which opens likes this via an AJAX call

```
$('#calendar-event-form-container').html(HTML).toggle();
$("#calendar-event-form-container").dialog({theme:'a'});
```

and closes by

```
$("#calendar-event-form-container").dialog('close');
$("#calendar-event-form-container").toggle();
```

Next time the dialog is opened it loses its JQM theme and position .

Can anybody see where the code has gone wrong?

Thanks in advance
Sincerely,
Babak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

andleer is correct, don't use toggle() with jQM, it is not needed. jQM dialog is created to be used as a separated page. Take a look at this example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="open-button">Open dialo</a>         
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
<!-- DIALOG BOX -->
<div data-role="page" id="dialog-box" data-theme="b">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Warning</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h3 id="dialog-msg">
            Dialog test
        </h3>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="close-button">
            Close dialog
        </a>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Also if possible you should open dialog box like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage('#dialog-box', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});
```

In case you are dynamically changing dialogbox content you must trigger pagecreate on it to restyle it correctly:

```
$('#dialog-box').trigger("pagecreate");
```

And here's a full jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/fXzWj/

Comment: Thanks, your solutions helped me to understand the dynamics of the JQM page. thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Showing and Hiding a form as a dialog with `toggle()` is non-standard. The jQuery Mobile dialog is designed to show or hide a page `<div data-role="page">` container. As such, it is assumed to be outside of the current page and won't be visible until displayed as a dialog.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dialog/index.html

"Any page can be presented as a modal dialog by adding the `data-rel="dialog"` attribute to the page anchor link"